# parse json string with html in it

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am using php to json encode an array and then parse it with jQuery's $.evalJSON()

to use it in the client side

```
$test = array(
    'Label' => array(
        'id' => '021780000002703007764835',
        'notes' => '<a id="test" href="javascript:void(0)">ici</a>'
    )
);
```

When encoded to json from php it produces

```
{"Label":{"id":"021780000002703007764835","notes":"<a id=\"test\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\">ici<\/a>"}}
```

However, when using the below js code to decode it I get a js error

```
var test = $.evalJSON('<?= $test; ?>');
```

When I remove the html markup, it decodes it fine. However, I need the markup and I am sure there is a way to decode it properly.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: can you print the instruction once it has been processed by php ? that could be an escaping problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 addslashes(json_encode($test));
```

I have successfully used this in the past for exactly this problem